# readLines to skip first line and read data as table/data frame

Tags: r

How can I use readLines to read in the below data?

I have tried many times but cannot get it into a data frame.

```
con = file('stdin', open ='r')
newData  = readLines(con, n = 2:20)

print(newData)
```

Data:

```
250
1/3/2012 16:00:00   Missing_1
1/4/2012 16:00:00   27.47
1/5/2012 16:00:00   27.728
1/6/2012 16:00:00   28.19
1/9/2012 16:00:00   28.1
1/10/2012 16:00:00  28.15
```

EDIT: The data comes from here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/missing-stock-prices/problem

I am just trying to connect to it.

```
con = file('stdin', open ='r')
newData = readLines(con)
newData = newData[-1]

newData <- data.frame(newData)
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Is Data the input or expected output?

Comment: Thanks, that looks better but I still cannot connect to it - I have added a small edit with what I am trying to do.

Comment: You can use something like this: `newData  <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(readLines()[-1], " +"))` to read the Input from STDIN.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? For ease of use, I saved the sample data that you have provided as a .txt file and tried reading that. Nevertheless, this should also work with other connection sources.

```
library(splitstackshape)

SampleData <- readLines(con <- file("C:/Users/Siddharth.A/Desktop/Sample.txt"))
SampleData <- SampleData[-1]
SampleData <- as.data.frame(SampleData,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
SampleData <- cSplit(SampleData,names(SampleData)," ")
```